# 2000 hrs a year as project management experience in application

Tags: pmp

I find conflicting information on how many hours I can claim a year as project management experience with some experts suggesting that I claim just 1500 hrs while others suggest claiming the full 2000 hours. I worked 8 hrs a day, 5 days a week, so I understand that I could claim 2000 hours but I have seen blogs with the suggestion that claiming more than 1500 can arouse suspicion. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing not from a PMI perspective but rather an auditor's perspective, claiming 2,000 hours in a year could signal suspicion.  Some most certainly log those kind of hours but I think it's on the tail end of the curve, where most log somewhere between 1,500 and 1,800 hours.  After you take into consideration holidays, sick, vacation, funeral, gaps between assignments, and other random unproductive time, getting to 2,000 hours takes consistent work above 50 hours a week.  Some do this kind of thing but it could be a signal that could trigger an audit.  Maybe not by itself but used with another signal or two, your application could get audited.  I don't work for PMI and have no idea what their criteria are but, as an auditor, the tail end of a curve on any metric typically triggers a deeper dive.

PS: Your statement that your worked 8 hours a day, five days a week would likely cause you grief.  The premise behind that statement is that you had 52 consecutive, perfect work weeks without vacations, holidays, sick, jury, funeral, gaps in work, training, and whatever else.  An auditor would not likely find that statement credible and would trigger even a deeper investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Only the certifying body (e.g. PMI) can really answer this type of question.

In my experience, 2000 hours distributed among project disciplines is very reasonable, and I doubt that will pique any suspicion.

The most important things are (1) to state hours truthfully and (2) be able to back them up, if necessary.